# Rails 3.2.2 - Right place for Mail configuration settings on Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

It's a little bit confusing since every people say it's going on a different place of the application.

I'have been testing but with no luck.

So, whereś the right place for it?

1. config/environment.rb?
2. config/application.rb?
3. config/environments/production.rb?
4. config/initializers/anymodelname.rb?

This is what I have been testing on several places.

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => "name@example.com",
    :password             => 'password',
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration suggests putting it in the `config/environments/$RAILS_ENV.rb` file so `config/environments/production.rb` would be the place to put it. When you say it does not work what errors are you getting?

Comment: @ScottJShea the problem is that the Gmail is actually seems to be 'blocking' certain accounts from use their address, like I was trying to do with my own email account from my domain, just trying to use the 'smtp.gmail.com`. After creating a gmail account and replacing, it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but seems that Google are only allowing Gmail accounts to use with their servers, I have just to create a new Gmail account and it works with no kind of special settings.